# How to import an exported IIFE, ES6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a Service file like this

```
// service.es6.js
   export default Service = (function($) {
      return { e: 5, f:3, setJQuery: val => $ = val }
   })(jQuery);
```

in another file, e.g. controller.es6.js

```
// controller.es6.js
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const jsdom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
const { window } = jsdom;
import * as jquery from "jquery";

const $ = require("jquery")(window);
const jQuery = $;

import * as MyService from './service.es6';
```

That gives me `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.

How can I import that properly?

Do I have to rewrite service into class instead?

Comment: That's creating a global `Service` variable?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely import jQuery into your Service module. That's the one trying to use it.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to import the jQuery in your service (any particular reason?), then you could change the IIFE to a factory like:

```
export default Service = function($) {
  return { e: 5, f:3, setJQuery: val => $ = val }
};

import serviceFactory from "./service.js";
const MyService = serviceFactory(jQuery);
```